# Azure Notification Hub doesn't seem to work with ios 10 and swift 3

Tags: ios, azure, azure-notificationhub

Details:
Swift version - 3.1
iOS version - 10.3 
I'm using WindowsAzureMessaging.framework.
I do follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started) precisely.

You can see other developers facing the same issue:

[Official GitHub rep](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/issues/32) 
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958462/microsoft-azure-remote-notifications-in-swift-3)

Will it ever be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS version 10 or higher you can use this fork of the official GitHub rep, you can find it here
https://github.com/pencildrummer/azure-notificationhubs/tree/master/iOS/bin

Because you are using swift, don't forget add `Bridging-Header.h` file into your project with included string - `#import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h"`